# Change Error Title in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, validation

how can i change the error title in silverlight?!!!
(1 Error)



[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Validation Summary has a Header property. You could simply set it in XAML or Codebehind and completely overwrite it.

If you need a bit more control, then override the HeaderTemplate. The default is too long to past here, but the important part is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myNewAndImprovedErrorHeaderThanksToMiguel">
   <!--There's a border, stackpanel and other funky, but irrelevant tags-->
   <TextBlock Padding="4,1,0,0" Text="{Binding}" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</DataTemplate/>
```

Now, you could simply use a converter for the Text to slightly modify it. The Binding's value will by default contain the text "# Error".